# Merge cells in Excel using "Openxml writer"

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, sax

I want to merge cells is excel. By using DOM approach I can do it easily. But as my excel file is too large, when I tries to get worksheet it throws Out of memory exception. So I have to use SAX approach to read excel file. But I dont know how to merge cells in this approach.
Searched a lot but every one gives the solution of DOM approach.

Can anyone help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes.. But with DOM approach only
the reason is.. to merge cells in Excel, you must have Cell reference. and that will be available only after Excel is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) :

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\example.xlsx")))
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    ws.Cells["A1:A2"].Merge = true;
    package.Save();
}
```

Comment: Cant use any other tool. We have functionality already implemented on production.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is: read the whole data from the old sheet by openxmlreader than write into new sheet by openxmlwriter, so I can add merge cell element after write data into sheetdata  element.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(YourExcelfileName, true))
        {
            // Create reference of main Workbook part, which contains all reference.
            WorkbookPart objworkbook = myDoc.WorkbookPart;

            // pick up first worksheet
            WorksheetPart objworksheet = objworkbook.WorksheetParts.First();

            // will be used in end while creating sheet data
            string objorigninalSheetId = objworkbook.GetIdOfPart(objworksheet);
            WorksheetPart objreplacementPart = objworkbook.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            string objreplacementPartId = objworkbook.GetIdOfPart(objreplacementPart);

            Sheets sheets = objworkbook.Workbook.Sheets;
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(objreplacementPart), SheetId = 2, Name = "Sheet" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            // Create object reader to read from excel file.
            OpenXmlReader objreader = OpenXmlReader.Create(objworksheet);

            // create writer object to write in excel sheet.
            OpenXmlWriter objOpenXmwriter = OpenXmlWriter.Create(objreplacementPart);

            objOpenXmwriter.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
            objOpenXmwriter.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());


            while (objreader.Read())
            {
            //read the context of original sheetdata.
            //then put all data to new sheetdata by openxmlwriter

            }

            // this is for Sheetdata
            objOpenXmwriter.WriteEndElement();

            //* after Sheetdata you can merge cells by openxmlwriter like that:    

            objOpenXmwriter.WriteStartElement(new MergeCells());
            objOpenXmwriter.WriteElement(new MergeCell() { Reference = "P1:Q1" });
            objOpenXmwriter.WriteElement(new MergeCell() { Reference = "R1:S1" });
            objOpenXmwriter.WriteEndElement();

            // this is for Worksheet
            objOpenXmwriter.WriteEndElement();

            //close all objects
            objreader.Close();
            objOpenXmwriter.Close();

            Sheet sheetreplace = objworkbook.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Id.Value.Equals(objorigninalSheetId)).First();
            sheetreplace.Id.Value = objreplacementPartId;
            objworkbook.DeletePart(objworksheet);

        }
```

The way of merge cells in Excel using Openxml writer is below:

```
objOpenXmwriter.WriteStartElement(new MergeCells());
objOpenXmwriter.WriteElement(new MergeCell() { Reference = "P1:Q1" });
objOpenXmwriter.WriteElement(new MergeCell() { Reference = "R1:S1" });
objOpenXmwriter.WriteEndElement();
```

References:

[Merge cell example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361473/merge-cells-in-excel-using-openxml-writer)

[Merge cell function](https://github.com/AlexanderAksyonov/OpenXMLWriterHelper/blob/master/OpenXmlHelper.cs#L232)

[openxmlwriter example](http://www.technetexperts.com/web/export-data-to-excel-using-openxml-sdk/)