# Merge cells in Excel using “Openxml writer”

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I want to merge cells in excel by using SAX approach with openxmlwriter. I have used these approach instead of DOM approach is to write thousands of records to excel.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your latest code?

Comment: Thousands is not a large number. Have you tried using a library like EPPlus?

Answer (score 3):

I am sharing piece of code which may help others to write code to merge cells using OpenXmlWriter (OpenXml SAX)

```
// OpenXMLWriter to write large data to excel to avoid System.OutOfMemoryException
OpenXmlWriter oxw = OpenXmlWriter.Create(wsPart);
oxw.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());

// Excel column style
oxw.WriteStartElement(new Columns());
foreach (var item in gridHeaderList)
{
    oxw.WriteStartElement(new Column(), new List<OpenXmlAttribute>()
    { 
        new OpenXmlAttribute("min", null, (item.columnIndex + 1).ToString()),
        new OpenXmlAttribute("max", null, (item.columnIndex + 1).ToString()),
        new OpenXmlAttribute("width", null, item.columnWidth.ToString())
    });

    oxw.WriteEndElement();
}

oxw.WriteEndElement();
// End of Columns element node

// Sheet data node
oxw.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

oxw.WriteStartElement(new Row());
foreach (var item in dataList)
{
    oxw.WriteElement(new Cell() 
        { 
            CellValue = new CellValue(item.Value), 
            DataType = CellValues.String, 
            StyleIndex = item.styleIndex 
        });
}
oxw.WriteEndElement();

oxw.WriteEndElement();
// End of sheetdata element node

// Start of MergeCells element node
// NOTE: Make sure initialize "A6:D6" range cells
oxw.WriteStartElement(new MergeCells());
oxw.WriteElement(new MergeCell() { Reference = new StringValue("A6:D6") });
oxw.WriteEndElement();

// End of MergeCells element node

oxw.WriteEndElement();
// End of worksheet element node

oxw.Close();
```

Comment: Code only answers without explanation don't help, especially when 90% of the code is *not* relevant to the question

Comment: Please find the code at the end and before closing worksheet element, This is what i need to merge cells using OpenXMLWriter.

Comment: Edit your question and explain why this is an answer. Remove the redundant code. This is *not* a helpful answer