# Append rows to the end of excel document using OpenXmlSDK c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I need to append rows to the end of xls/xlsx document with OpenXmlSDK.

There [is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665307/openxml-add-new-row-to-existing-excel-file) question but suggested approach allocates entire sheet in memory which throws Out Of Memory for my case.

I followed [SAX approach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk/) but it also generates Out of memory.

Is there a way to `xlsx` file for append? I have not found such option in `OpenXmlWriter`.

```
  private static void OpenXMLSDKAppendRows(string fileName, int numRows, int numCols)
    {
        {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, true))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

                using (OpenXmlWriter openXmlWriter = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetPart))
                {
                    Row row = new Row();
                    Cell cell = new Cell();
                    CellValue value = new CellValue("Test");
                    cell.AppendChild(value);

                    openXmlWriter.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
                    openXmlWriter.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());
                    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++)
                    {
                        openXmlWriter.WriteStartElement(row);
                        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < numCols; colIndex++)
                        {
                            openXmlWriter.WriteElement(cell);
                        }
                        openXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    openXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    openXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

                    openXmlWriter.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can not use `EPPlus` because of LGPL license.

Comment: Is the exception thrown beacuse of the large volume of data You are trying to append or size of the original file? Is it thrown when the code is run on a small file with only few rows to be added?

Comment: @lukasz-m that particular snippet throws out of memory. OpenXmlReader allocates lots of data in memory. I need kind of append solution which .Net StreamWriter has